# C# accessing value-type properties like variables

Tags: c#, properties, value-type

I'd like to know whether the following is possible with C# properties.

I have a class "Transform" that holds a 4x4 matrix in a private member field. Now I want to create a property like this:

```
    Matrix m;
    public Vector3 Position
    {
        get { return new Vector3(m[12], m[13], m[14]); }
        set { m[12] = value.X; m[13] = value.Y; m[14] = value.Z; }
    }
```

but i'd like to provide the following functionality:

```
    Transform myTransform = new Transform();
    myTransform.Position.X += 3.0f;
```

such that the Property directly can be changed as if it was a variable. is this somehow possible with C#? (Vector3 and Matrix both are structs.)

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this won't work. Think about it - your getters and setters are really *doing* something. You can't bypass them without changing the semantics completely, and I wouldn't expect a setter to run just because I changed something in what the getter had returned.

Do you really *have* to have mutable structs to start with? You'll find all kinds of corner cases and weirdnesses. Why not make them immutable, and write:

```
myTransform.Position = myTransform.Position.OffsetBy(3.0f, 0f, 0f);
```

or

```
myTransform.OffSetPosition(3.0f, 0f, 0f);
```

That would save you having to build the `Vector3` in the first place.

Mutable structs are very, very rarely the right solution. In a very few cases they *may* be reasonable for performance reasons, but I'd explore all other options first.

Comment: you should have business hours, so that the rest of us know when to bother answering questions... :D

Comment: hey Jon!

yeah sure, i add those functions too, but if it is possible i'd like to offer the possibility to change them directly just for convenience. I just thoght that it technically should be easy to implement the functionality of automatically creating a copy of the property value, change the content of it and then reassign it - so i expected it to be possible somehow...

Answer (score 0):

As Jon said, it's just a bad idea.  Whenever you're dealing with simple value types (and a Vector3 qualifies), you're better off making them immutable.

If you're really determined, you can get *close* to what you want, but it takes some work.

```
public struct Vector3
{
    public Vector3(float X, float Y, float Z, VectorListener listener)
    {
        m_x = X;
        m_y = Y;
        m_z = Z;
        m_listener = listener;
    }
    private VectorListener m_listener;
    private float m_x;
    private float m_y;
    private float m_z;

    public float X
    {
        get{return m_x;}
        set{ m_x = value; m_listener.SetVector(this);}
    }
    public float Y
    {
        get { return m_y; }
        set { m_y = value; m_listener.SetVector(this); }
    }
    public float Z
    {
        get { return m_z; }
        set { m_z = value; m_listener.SetVector(this); }
    }

}
public interface VectorListener
{
    void SetVector(Vector3 vec);
}
public class Transform : VectorListener
{
    private bool m_receivedUpdate;
    public Vector3 MyVector { get{return new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, this);} }
    public void SetVector(Vector3 vec)
    {
        ReceivedUpdate = true;
    }
    public bool ReceivedUpdate { get; set; }
}

    // and the test... test class omitted for brevity
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Transform transform = new Transform();
        Assert.IsFalse(transform.ReceivedUpdate);

        // the following won't compile
        //transform.MyVector.X = 3.0f;

        // but this will work
        Vector3 vec = transform.MyVector;
        vec.X = 3.0f;
        Assert.IsTrue(transform.ReceivedUpdate);

    }
```

That being said, *don't do this.*  I would immediately reject any code review that contained code like this.